# Ask user a question and place the answer in a cell using Google Script

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a simple Google Script inside of Google Sheets where, once the user runs the function from a custom menu (I have already created that), the user is prompted with a question.  I want to place that text answer they provided into a specific cell.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try using an input box: var value = Browser.inputBox('Your question here'); cell.setValue(value);

Comment: Can this be used inside of Script Editor?

Comment: If the script is bound to a spreadsheet, yes; but the input box will show in the spreadsheet. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, the script is bound to the spreadsheet, it will only be used by me.  I want the user to answer a question, and it will place that answer is a specific cell, like B2.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Did it work for you?

Comment: I did, and the box popped up and I was able to type in it.  But where is the command to save what I typed into cell B2?  Also said "cell is not defined" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function and modify where necessary.

```
function setAnswer() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheetNameHere');
var cell = sheet.getRange('B2');

var answer = Browser.inputBox('Your question here');

cell.setValue(answer);
}
```

If you want to specify the cell each time, you can use an inputBox for that, too.

```
function setAnswer() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
//line above changed to reflect dynamic use of function

var rangeA1 = Browser.inputBox('Please type the cell reference you wish to save your answer in:');

var cell = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);

var answer = Browser.inputBox('Your question here');

cell.setValue(answer);
}
```

Comment: YES!! Perfect, thank you so much.  So simple, yet it was driving me crazy for hours.